# Playing youtube videos in MPMovieplayerController does violate youtube TOS?

Tags: ios, youtube

I am extracting the streaming URL of videos from the youtube mobile site by analysing the JSON for the video url and getting the streaming url, then play it directly using MPMoviePlayerController in IOS.

It's not using UIWebView. I don't save the video to the disk, just playing only. Does it violate Youtube TOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It violates Youtube's TOS.

Refer to Youtube's TOS [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms).

Under II(10), it says

> Your API Client will not, and You will not encourage or create
>   functionality for Your users or other third parties to access any
>   portion of any YouTube audiovisual content by any means other than use
>   of a YouTube player or other video player expressly authorized by
>   YouTube.

Comment: Isn't iOS player authorized by youtube ?